# Adding content to variable

Tags: php

sorry I don't know the exact term for this.
I'ld like to add content to "mymeta" from the loops and echos.
I tried this but it's not working:

```
     $mymeta = if (strlen($finalArray['Title']) > 0){
       echo $finalArray['Title'] . " | ";
    }   
    +
    else if (strlen($finalArray['Name']) > 0){
       echo $finalArray['Name'] . " | ";
    }   
    +
    else if (strlen($finalArray['Caption']) > 0){
       echo $finalArray['Caption'] . " | ";
    } 
+
echo $finalArray['Date'] . " | " ;
```

Thanks for tips.

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to conditionally append to mymeta. My solution is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this is what you're after.

```
$mymeta = "";
if (strlen($finalArray['Title']) > 0) {
    $mymeta .= $finalArray['Title'] . " | ";
}
else if (strlen($finalArray['Name']) > 0) {
    $mymeta .= $finalArray['Name'] . " | ";
}
else if (strlen($finalArray['Caption']) > 0) {
    $mymeta .= $finalArray['Caption'] . " | ";
} 

$mymeta .= $finalArray['Date'] . " | " ;
```

Comment: Do you need the `echo` at the end?

Comment: Nope, just caught that. Thanks :)